# Get user to set permission in Sharepoint library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I am using the following syntax to get the value of User but i am always getting null and exception

```
 UserCollection users = ctx.Web.SiteUsers;
                ctx.Load(users);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                User user = (from User c in users where c.Title == username select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What kind of exception you are getting? Variable ``username`` contains users display name or login?

Comment: exception is 'Value is Null' and username has login name i am also trying with email but doesn't work.

Now i did the same thing using the foreach loop and it works making the process slower, what is wrong in this condition?

Comment: You are comparing users display name (Title) with login name. You shoud use ``c.LoginName == "i:0#.f|membership|" + username``.